# getc is printing garbage when it should stop after end of file

Tags: c

What is wrong with the program?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
main(   )
{
  char * buf="robot.c";
  char c;int i=0;   
  FILE*fp=fopen(buf,"r");
  if(!fp)
    printf("open error\n");
  while(1)
    {
      //printf("size%c\n",*fp->_IO_read_ptr);
      //while((c=getc(fp))>0)
      c=getc(fp);
      printf("%c",c);
      //getc(fp);
      //printf("new size%c\n",*fp->_IO_read_end);
      for(;i<1000000000;i++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it stop at end of file? You never check for that.

Comment: Please look up the `getc` function and use it correctly.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Post that as an answer.

Comment: You should stop program or do not access file if file could not open, it would be -> `if(!fp){ printf("open error\n"); return 0; }`

Comment: @Barmar Is it `undefined behavior` reading after EOF **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan See http://computer-programming-forum.com/47-c-language/80fd475dcadcbf61.htm for a discussion of continuing to read after `gets()` returns `EOF`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! Got it, its also written in [manual](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/getc.html) its returns EOF.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That's not a manual, it's just some guy's website. And it doesn't say what it does if you keep reading after EOF.

Comment: "it should stop after end of file" -- Why do you say so?

Answer (score 6):

As @Barmar noticed, you don't check and break the while loop when EOF is found, so it printf garbage.

Instead, write your while like:

```
while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF){
      printf("%c",c);
      for(;i<1000000000;i++);
}
```

note: `c` **must** be an int in order to hold an EOF-value.
A very good Read: [Definition of EOF and how to use it effectively](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1048865140)

Comment: Please note: `c` **must** be an `int` in order to hold an EOF-value.

Comment: The "garbage" it prints is specifically an unending repetition of (char)EOF

Comment: @michaelb958 I would like to share [a link](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1048865140) with you. thanks for your comment.